# Why this happening I don't have line 86

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, simplecv, webiopi

I tried the run this and i just used spaces not tabs but

```
import time
import sys
import numpy as np
import SimpleCV
import webiopi
from ayarlar import *

GPIO = webiopi.GPIO
GPIO.setFunction(4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setFunction(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setFunction(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setFunction(27, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setFunction(10, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setFunction(25, GPIO.OUT)

def dist_from_color(img_color):
    matrix = (img.getNumpy()[:,:,[2,1,0]] - color) ** 2
    width, height = img.size()
    return matirx.sum() ** 0.5 / (width * height)

def forward():
   GPIO.digitalWrite(18, GPIO.HIGH)
   GPIO.digitalWrite(10, GPIO.LOW)

def reverse():
   GPIO.digitalWrite(18, GPIO.LOW)
   GPIO.digitalWrite(10, GPIO.HIGH)

def right():
   GPIO.digitalWrite(27, GPIO.HIGH)
   GPIO.digitalWrite(25, GPIO.LOW)

def left():
   GPIO.digitalWrite(27, GPIO.LOW)
   GPIO.digitalWrite(25, GPIO.HIGH)

def strop():
   GPIO.digitalWrite(18, GPIO.LOW)
   GPIO.digitalWrite(10, GPIO.LOW)
   GPIO.digitalWrite(27, GPIO.LOW)
   GPIO.digitalWrite(25, GPIO.LOW)

@webiopi.macro
def ButtonForward():
   forward()

@webiopi.macro
def ButtonReverse():
   reverse()

@webiopi.macro
def ButtonTrunLeft():
   left()

@webiopi.macro
def ButtonTrunRight():
   right()
@webiopi.macro
def ButtonStop():
   stop()
def main():
    try:
     print(__doc__)
     GPIO.digitalWrite(4, GPIO.HIGH)
     GPIO.digitalWrite(17, GPIO.HIGH)
     server = webiopi.Server(port=80)
     server.addMacro(ButtonForward)
     server.addMacro(ButtonReverse)
     server.addMacro(ButtonTrunLeft)
     server.addMacro(ButtonTrunRight)
     server.addMacro(ButtonStop)
     cam = SimpleCV.Camera()
     background = cam.getImage()
     print("Tespite Baslaniyor")
     while True:
        try:
           background = cam.getImage()
           time.sleep(0.1)
           img = cam.getImage()
           to_show = img
           to_show.save("../../..//usr/share/webiopi/htdocs/aaa.jpg")
           dist = ((img - background) + (background - img)).dilate(6)   
        except(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
           del cam
           server.stop()
```

It gives me this eror even i don't have line 86

File "tespit.py", line 86                         ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
Please help me i can't solve the problem...

Comment: It looks like your `except` needs an extra space in front of it I think

Comment: Actually I think your indentation is not quite right in your first `try` block

Comment: You have two `try`s and only one `except`. Something's not right here.

Comment: I think as a learning exercise when debugging something like this is to step through it using a competent debugger

Comment: Line 86 is non-existent, while python wants it as it wants to match the first `try` with an `except`.

Comment: sometimes you indent by 1, sometimes by 3. This will not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two `try` statements, and only one `except` statement.

Add an `except` clause for the first `try`, at the end of the `main` function, indented 4 spaces, and it will work.

Line 86 is just past the end of your code, and is where Python is looking for a matching `except`.

Answer (score 0):

Every `try` must have at least one matching `except`.
And you should clean up GPIOs before stop Webiopi server.